# Android 2.2 - and exchange password policy enforcement

Tags: android, passwords, exchange-server, policy

In Android 2.2 site ([link text](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.2-highlights.html))

it's written:
Improved security with the addition of numeric pin or alpha-numeric password options to unlock device. Exchange administrators can enforce password policy across devices

But while I'm using N1 with 2.2 and try to connect to my company exchange server it didn't enforce me to set a password, although connecting to the same server from Windows Mobile 6 device enforce this.
I know that exchange server is configured to enforce password. Is there anything special the administrator need to do?

Thank you,
Moshe

Answer (score 0):

See issue [link text](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8601)

You should configure your exchange server not to use "Allow non-provisionable devices" option.

Regards,
Moshe